# childbrowser on iPhone vs Android?

Tags: android

I use the childbrowser in my jqtouch - phonegap iPhone app and have now created it in Eclipse aswell, I have got the childbrowser to work in Android.

1. In the iPhone the childbrowser has a Done button and in the Android it opens a window with a address field at the top, is this how it suppose to look like - work?
2. When I open a .pdf or .doc document in the iPhone it opens in the childbrowser so I can read it, but in the Android it downloads the document, is this what it suppose to do?

If so, is there a way to open .pdfs so you can read it without downloading it first?
3. Is the childbrowser suppose to work in the emulator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, that's how it's supposed to work. The child browser is a bit non-idiomatic on the Android platform, since the Android way is generally more to open content that isn't native to the app on another app where it is (see question 2). The typical way in Android when you encounter a link is rather to open the web browser with that link, but in iOS the Child Brower UI pattern is very common. The Child Browser Android plugin also have a way of sending links to the web browser, I'd recommend you try it and consider using that instead of the Child Browser for your Android app version.
2. Also yes, that's also how Android generally works. Creating in-app viewers for .doc of .pdf -files would be too difficult if that's not the app's primary task.